# What is the difference between the while and until loops in ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops, while-loop

In Ruby there are to loops that appear to do the exact same thing as each other, the **while** and **until** loops.

What would be a situation to use one over the other and why does Ruby have two loops that seem to do the same thing?

The while loops syntax is as follows:

```
while conditional [do]
   code
end
```

And the **until** syntax:

```
until conditional [do]
   code
end
```

So to make this as clear as possible:

```
$i = 0
$num = 5

while $i < $num  do
   puts("Inside the loop i = #$i" )
   $i +=1
end
```

And

```
$i = 0
$num = 5

until $i < $num  do
   puts("Inside the loop i = #$i" )
   $i +=1;
end
```

Will produce both the same out put of:

```
Inside the loop i = 0
Inside the loop i = 1
Inside the loop i = 2
Inside the loop i = 3
Inside the loop i = 4
```

Comment: *"Will produce both the same output"* - nope

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ruby allows multiple ways of doing exactly the same thing, so that the code can read naturally depending on which sounds better for you and the code you are writing. Sometimes a conditional works better in the positive eg `something_is_happening?` vs the negative `something_is_done`

and `while` works while something positive is continuing to be positive, whereas `until` continues the loop until something negative occurs.

eg

```
while 'yes' == keep_going do
   keep_going = get_answer
end
```

vs

```
until 'stop' == answer do
   answer = get_answer
end
```

Also i note that you haven't actually tried running your two loops in irb...I know this because the output of the second one is definitely not the same as the first.

```
2.1.2 :008 > $i = 0
 => 0 
2.1.2 :009 > $num = 5
 => 5 
2.1.2 :010 > 
2.1.2 :011 >   until $i < $num  do
2.1.2 :012 >        puts("Inside the loop i = #$i" )
2.1.2 :013?>      $i +=1;
2.1.2 :014 >     end
 => nil
```

This is because when ruby interprets "is `$i < $num` yet" it evaluates to true and then stops immediately.

Answer (score 1):

`until` can also be used to get the same result as `while`.

In this case `until $i >= $num do` works similarly to `while $i < $num`

```
2.4.0 :002 > $i = 0
 => 0 
2.4.0 :003 > $num = 5
 => 5 
2.4.0 :004 > until $i >= $num do
2.4.0 :005 >     puts("Inside the loop i = #$i")
2.4.0 :006?>   $i += 1 
2.4.0 :007?>   end
```